# Protractor and promises

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

A lot of the functions exposed by Protractor return promises.

Do I need to structure my Jasmine tests using Protractor using things like async tests (with the `done` parameter), and `.then`, or does Protractor provide some magic to do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDriverJS takes care of that with the control-flow. Protractor adds the modification of Jasmine's `expect` to keep the `then`s at bay. It's best explained [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md).

Comment: So if I have some set up (e.g navigation or running a script on the client using `executeScript`, or even selection of elements using `element(by.css...)`) in a `beforeEach`, do I have to use normal promise syntax using `then`?

Comment: No, `beforeEach` is the same as an `it` block in all regards, except at when it gets executed. Take a look at this question for an example of how `then` works in regards to the control-flow and when we might need it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949492/protractor-page-object-is-not-updating-when-the-dom-elements-are-changed/30958529#30958529

Comment: I presume it is important to surface promises from async utility methods, for example methods on PageObjects. Otherwise, protractor will not "know" to enagage its magic?

Comment: To add an async call outside of protractor's domain to the control-flow, you can use `browser.controlFlow().execute(promiseFunc)` where `promiseFunc` is a function that returns a promise. All nicely explained here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#control-flows

Comment: Actually, what I mean is: say I have a utility function `foo` that under the hood is using `browser.driver.findElement`, *but that does not return the promise*. If I make an invocation to `foo` from inside a `beforeEach`, I presume this will cause problems because the promise is not returned and hence made visible to protractor?

Comment: `browser.driver.findElement` would register the promise with the current control-flow no matter where you call it from. Also, there's an alias for it - [`element`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#step-1---interacting-with-elements)

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you point me to the location in the documentation that would tell me whether browser.executeScript adds to the control-flow, or can I assume any method on browser will do so?

Comment: The [official documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) says it returns a `webdriver.Promise` which is a sign of just that. Best to check the [source-code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L528). It calls `schedule` which in turn calls `flow.execute`

Comment: OK thanks. If choose to use (or not) the promises returned from these functions then will the execution order (from the client's perspective) be the same? For example `browser.executeScript(...).then(function () { browser.navigate (...); )` is that the same as `browser.executeScript(...); browser.navigate(...);`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is some *magic* that protractor performs in order to wait for each promise to resolve.

The best description of the process is in the protractor documentation: [How It Works](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/infrastructure).

This means we don't have to structure the tests as async using a `done`.  We can simply assert using `expect` (in Jasmine) and everything should work.